# Why does Microsoft Text analytics API return neutral sentiment for a sentence with strong negative connotation?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, text-analytics-api

I am trying to build app to analyze sentiment of survey data using Microsoft Analytics API. One of the survey response has Strong negative connotation

> *Personally, there is not a company in the world that needs this*
>   *product*

but API returns a score of 50. What is the reason for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried on their page and it looks like it has changed and is reporting back a sentiment of 73%.

[image: Sentiment]

I think I know why, though. In the "key phrases" the word "not" wasn't picked up. Looking at the stop words from `nltk`, it seems that "not" is a stop word.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop_words = stopwords.words("english")

[word for word in stop_words if word == "not"]  # Returns ['not']
```

Since "not" may have been removed as a stop word there is no negativity to give a negative sentiment.